# Catch double entry in an array

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I want to store elements having a unique name in a list so I can easily display them.

```
[
  {
    name: 'foo',
    test: 'randomString'
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    test: 'moreStrings'
  }
]
```

to check if there is a double entry I have to loop through all elements to check if the name is unique. It would be easier when I store it like this because I can check with `moduls/:name` if it exists:

```
{
  foo: {
    test: 'randomString'
  },
  bar: {
    test: 'moreStrings'
  }
}
```

But `*ngFor="let modul of moduls | async"` wants something like `FirebaseListObservable` and not `FirebaseObjectObservable`

I think the second way is better, but I have no idea how to do it so everything is still synced.

Comment: you can remove duplicate entry using loop

Comment: but how? I tried it with a `foreach` but it failed

Answer (score 0):

Angular itself won't help you here.
You'd need to prepare your array before you pass it on to `*ngFor`.

Have a look at [ts-linq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-linq). I haven't used it myself yet (but will try it soon) but from the doc it seems to provide full `linq` functionality. You'd want `Distinct` for your case.